# Bind keys for history search in vim

Tags: vi, oh-my-zsh

By default, you can cycle through the history of commands by pressing the up arrow. I want to customize it. I prefer to use Ctr-n instead of the up arrow. How can I do that?

As a note, I use oh-my-zsh with the [history substring search](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/history-substring-search) plugin. The documentation of the plugin say it is possible to use the plugin in vi mode. However, the plugin has no effect on my vi.

Comment: *vi mode* is a set of keymaps defined in `zsh`, where it uses key bindings similar to those in the `vi` editor to navigate and edit the command line. There is also an *emacs mode*, which is the default setting with *Oh-My-Zsh*. The documentation of the plugin just says, that the plugin will work with (and probably has bindings for) `zsh`'s *vi mode*. It has nothing to do with the `vi` editor itself.

Answer (score 0):

By default ctrl-p takes you to the previous command and ctrl-n takes you to the next command (if you press it on an empty command line, nothing will happen). You would be best off using ctrl-p for this behavior.

However, if you really do want to change the above behavior, add this to your .vimrc:
`cnoremap <C-n> <C-p>`.